# Suspension on my computer under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit won't work properly

Tags: 14.04, suspend

I have a problem about suspension procedure under Ubuntu 14.04. It won't work properly; that is I can activate it, but when trying to resume the system it restarts, as if I had turned it off and then on again. Any ideas about possible actions in order to solve the problem?

Some commands about the hardware:

**`sudo lshw -C video`**

```
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3410/3430]
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 00 
width: 32 bits 
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
resources: irq:48 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d0020000-d002ffff memory:d0000000-d001ffff
```

**`uname -a`**

> Linux tryitandsee 3.16.0-45-generic #60~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24
>   21:16:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: maybe an explanation on how you're doing what you're doing would help. As in, how are you suspending, and how are you trying to resume?

Comment: By clicking "Suspend" on the top menu bar; to resume it I press "enter" .

Comment: Can't duplicate this issue on my machine. What happens if you press the power button to suspend, and then again to resume? Don't hold it down in either case, just a single press.

Comment: I don't understand what you should duplicate.  Pressing the power button or taking any other action to suspend doesn't change the situation. Suspending doesn't work properly because the pc, instead of resuming from suspension, starts again when pressing any possible button.

Answer (score -1):

By editing the `/etc/default/grub` file I succeeded in resolving the issue:

- First of all backup your file on your Desktop:

  `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /home/username/Desktop/grub`
- Then edit the `/etc/default/grub` in order to change two lines
  in the way below ; so run:

  `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

  ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
  ```
- Run:

  `sudo update-grub`
- Restart your pc. You could need restarting it a few times before
  suspension comes back working properly.
- Should anything go wrong or this method not work, run this command:

  - `sudo cp /home/username/Desktop/grub /etc/default/grub`
  - `sudo update-grub`

I hope this solution can help as many people as possible. See you around. Bye.

Comment: It does not work for me.